# Magento product rendering

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I have some doubts regarding product rendering.When we add a product from admin how it is displayed from frontend. What Magento does to make their product visible and distinguishable by their type like simple product,configurable.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Product type is distinguished by **type_id** which is field or attribute of products. If you `echo $_product->getTyeId()` then you will get the product type(simple, configurable, grouped etc).

Products are visible in frontend based on few things.

1. Visibility should be catalog, search or catalog search
2. Status should be Enabled
3. a) if type is configurable, grouped, bundle then it should be in stock

   b) if simple then in stock with quantity greater than 0(if manage stock 
         set to yes)
4. There is also an option which enables to show out of stock products in frontend.

Comment: Hi @sukumar thank you for your reply. I want to know technical part not the functional.How Magento renders products at frontend by using backend data?